# Fixing My 'Save' Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some code that you can select players and assign them teams using a drag and drop technique. Now, is it possible that with the click of the 'Save' button, that it saves which team each player is in. I know localStorage could work but I am not sure how to implement this into my code.

Note: In order for the code to work you have to copy the code and save it as a HTML file on you computer. Then the code will work just fine.

```js
/* VARIABLES YOU COULD MODIFY */
var boxSizeArray = [13,13,13,13,13,13]; // Array indicating how many items there is rooom for in the right column ULs

var arrow_offsetX = -5; // Offset X - position of small arrow
var arrow_offsetY = 0; // Offset Y - position of small arrow

var arrow_offsetX_firefox = -6; // Firefox - offset X small arrow
var arrow_offsetY_firefox = -13; // Firefox - offset Y small arrow

var verticalSpaceBetweenListItems = 3; // Pixels space between one <li> and next
          // Same value or higher as margin bottom in CSS for #dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer ul li,#dragContent li


var indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow = false; // Display arrow to indicate where object will be dropped(false = use rectangle)

var cloneSourceItems = false; // Items picked from main container will be cloned(i.e. "copy" instead of "cut").
var cloneAllowDuplicates = true; // Allow multiple instances of an item inside a small box(example: drag Student 1 to team A twice

/* END VARIABLES YOU COULD MODIFY */

var dragDropTopContainer = false;
var dragTimer = -1;
var dragContentObj = false;
var contentToBeDragged = false; // Reference to dragged <li>
var contentToBeDragged_src = false; // Reference to parent of <li> before drag started
var contentToBeDragged_next = false;  // Reference to next sibling of <li> to be dragged
var destinationObj = false; // Reference to <UL> or <LI> where element is dropped.
var dragDropIndicator = false; // Reference to small arrow indicating where items will be dropped
var ulPositionArray = new Array();
var mouseoverObj = false; // Reference to highlighted DIV

var MSIE = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE')>=0?true:false;
var navigatorVersion = navigator.appVersion.replace(/.*?MSIE (\d\.\d).*/g,'$1')/1;


var indicateDestinationBox = false;
function getTopPos(inputObj)
{
  var returnValue = inputObj.offsetTop;
  while((inputObj = inputObj.offsetParent) != null){
   if(inputObj.tagName!='HTML')returnValue += inputObj.offsetTop;
  }
  return returnValue;
}

function getLeftPos(inputObj)
{
  var returnValue = inputObj.offsetLeft;
  while((inputObj = inputObj.offsetParent) != null){
   if(inputObj.tagName!='HTML')returnValue += inputObj.offsetLeft;
  }
  return returnValue;
}

function cancelEvent()
{
 return false;
}
function initDrag(e) // Mouse button is pressed down on a LI
{
 if(document.all)e = event;
 var st = Math.max(document.body.scrollTop,document.documentElement.scrollTop);
 var sl = Math.max(document.body.scrollLeft,document.documentElement.scrollLeft);

 dragTimer = 0;
 dragContentObj.style.left = e.clientX + sl + 'px';
 dragContentObj.style.top = e.clientY + st + 'px';
 contentToBeDragged = this;
 contentToBeDragged_src = this.parentNode;
 contentToBeDragged_next = false;
 if(this.nextSibling){
  contentToBeDragged_next = this.nextSibling;
  if(!this.tagName && contentToBeDragged_next.nextSibling)contentToBeDragged_next = contentToBeDragged_next.nextSibling;
 }
 timerDrag();
 return false;
}

function timerDrag()
{
 if(dragTimer>=0 && dragTimer<10){
  dragTimer++;
  setTimeout('timerDrag()',10);
  return;
 }
 if(dragTimer==10){

  if(cloneSourceItems && contentToBeDragged.parentNode.id=='allItems'){
   newItem = contentToBeDragged.cloneNode(true);
   newItem.onmousedown = contentToBeDragged.onmousedown;
   contentToBeDragged = newItem;
  }
  dragContentObj.style.display='block';
  dragContentObj.appendChild(contentToBeDragged);
 }
}

function moveDragContent(e)
{
 if(dragTimer<10){
  if(contentToBeDragged){
   if(contentToBeDragged_next){
    contentToBeDragged_src.insertBefore(contentToBeDragged,contentToBeDragged_next);
   }else{
    contentToBeDragged_src.appendChild(contentToBeDragged);
   }
  }
  return;
 }
 if(document.all)e = event;
 var st = Math.max(document.body.scrollTop,document.documentElement.scrollTop);
 var sl = Math.max(document.body.scrollLeft,document.documentElement.scrollLeft);


 dragContentObj.style.left = e.clientX + sl + 'px';
 dragContentObj.style.top = e.clientY + st + 'px';

 if(mouseoverObj)mouseoverObj.className='';
 destinationObj = false;
 dragDropIndicator.style.display='none';
 if(indicateDestinationBox)indicateDestinationBox.style.display='none';
 var x = e.clientX + sl;
 var y = e.clientY + st;
 var width = dragContentObj.offsetWidth;
 var height = dragContentObj.offsetHeight;

 var tmpOffsetX = arrow_offsetX;
 var tmpOffsetY = arrow_offsetY;
 if(!document.all){
  tmpOffsetX = arrow_offsetX_firefox;
  tmpOffsetY = arrow_offsetY_firefox;
 }

 for(var no=0;no<ulPositionArray.length;no++){
  var ul_leftPos = ulPositionArray[no]['left'];
  var ul_topPos = ulPositionArray[no]['top'];
  var ul_height = ulPositionArray[no]['height'];
  var ul_width = ulPositionArray[no]['width'];

  if((x+width) > ul_leftPos && x<(ul_leftPos + ul_width) && (y+height)> ul_topPos && y<(ul_topPos + ul_height)){
   var noExisting = ulPositionArray[no]['obj'].getElementsByTagName('LI').length;
   if(indicateDestinationBox && indicateDestinationBox.parentNode==ulPositionArray[no]['obj'])noExisting--;
   if(noExisting<boxSizeArray[no-1] || no==0){
    dragDropIndicator.style.left = ul_leftPos + tmpOffsetX + 'px';
    var subLi = ulPositionArray[no]['obj'].getElementsByTagName('LI');

    var clonedItemAllreadyAdded = false;
    if(cloneSourceItems && !cloneAllowDuplicates){
     for(var liIndex=0;liIndex<subLi.length;liIndex++){
      if(contentToBeDragged.id == subLi[liIndex].id)clonedItemAllreadyAdded = true;
     }
     if(clonedItemAllreadyAdded)continue;
    }

    for(var liIndex=0;liIndex<subLi.length;liIndex++){
     var tmpTop = getTopPos(subLi[liIndex]);
     if(!indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow){
      if(y<tmpTop){
       destinationObj = subLi[liIndex];
       indicateDestinationBox.style.display='block';
       subLi[liIndex].parentNode.insertBefore(indicateDestinationBox,subLi[liIndex]);
       break;
      }
     }else{
      if(y<tmpTop){
       destinationObj = subLi[liIndex];
       dragDropIndicator.style.top = tmpTop + tmpOffsetY - Math.round(dragDropIndicator.clientHeight/2) + 'px';
       dragDropIndicator.style.display='block';
       break;
      }
     }
    }

    if(!indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow){
     if(indicateDestinationBox.style.display=='none'){
      indicateDestinationBox.style.display='block';
      ulPositionArray[no]['obj'].appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);
     }

    }else{
     if(subLi.length>0 && dragDropIndicator.style.display=='none'){
      dragDropIndicator.style.top = getTopPos(subLi[subLi.length-1]) + subLi[subLi.length-1].offsetHeight + tmpOffsetY + 'px';
      dragDropIndicator.style.display='block';
     }
     if(subLi.length==0){
      dragDropIndicator.style.top = ul_topPos + arrow_offsetY + 'px'
      dragDropIndicator.style.display='block';
     }
    }

    if(!destinationObj)destinationObj = ulPositionArray[no]['obj'];
    mouseoverObj = ulPositionArray[no]['obj'].parentNode;
    mouseoverObj.className='mouseover';
    return;
   }
  }
 }
}

/* End dragging
Put <LI> into a destination or back to where it came from.
*/
function dragDropEnd(e)
{
 if(dragTimer==-1)return;
 if(dragTimer<10){
  dragTimer = -1;
  return;
 }
 dragTimer = -1;
 if(document.all)e = event;


 if(cloneSourceItems && (!destinationObj || (destinationObj && (destinationObj.id=='allItems' || destinationObj.parentNode.id=='allItems')))){
  contentToBeDragged.parentNode.removeChild(contentToBeDragged);
 }else{

  if(destinationObj){
   if(destinationObj.tagName=='UL'){
    destinationObj.appendChild(contentToBeDragged);
   }else{
    destinationObj.parentNode.insertBefore(contentToBeDragged,destinationObj);
   }
   mouseoverObj.className='';
   destinationObj = false;
   dragDropIndicator.style.display='none';
   if(indicateDestinationBox){
    indicateDestinationBox.style.display='none';
    document.body.appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);
   }
   contentToBeDragged = false;
   return;
  }
  if(contentToBeDragged_next){
   contentToBeDragged_src.insertBefore(contentToBeDragged,contentToBeDragged_next);
  }else{
   contentToBeDragged_src.appendChild(contentToBeDragged);
  }
 }
 contentToBeDragged = false;
 dragDropIndicator.style.display='none';
 if(indicateDestinationBox){
  indicateDestinationBox.style.display='none';
  document.body.appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);

 }
 mouseoverObj = false;

}

/*
Preparing data to be saved
*/
function saveDragDropNodes()
{
 var saveString = "";
 var uls = dragDropTopContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL');
 for(var no=0;no<uls.length;no++){ // LOoping through all <ul>
  var lis = uls[no].getElementsByTagName('LI');
  for(var no2=0;no2<lis.length;no2++){
   if(saveString.length>0)saveString = saveString + ";";
   saveString = saveString + uls[no].id + '|' + lis[no2].id;
  }
 }

 document.getElementById('saveContent').innerHTML = '<h1>Ready to save these nodes:</h1> ' + saveString.replace(/;/g,';<br>') + '<p>Format: ID of ul |(pipe) ID of li;(semicolon)</p><p>You can put these values into a hidden form fields, post it to the server and explode the submitted value there</p>';

}

function initDragDropScript()
{
 dragContentObj = document.getElementById('dragContent');
 dragDropIndicator = document.getElementById('dragDropIndicator');
 dragDropTopContainer = document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer');
 document.documentElement.onselectstart = cancelEvent;;
 var listItems = dragDropTopContainer.getElementsByTagName('LI'); // Get array containing all <LI>
 var itemHeight = false;
 for(var no=0;no<listItems.length;no++){
  listItems[no].onmousedown = initDrag;
  listItems[no].onselectstart = cancelEvent;
  if(!itemHeight)itemHeight = listItems[no].offsetHeight;
  if(MSIE && navigatorVersion/1<6){
   listItems[no].style.cursor='hand';
  }
 }

 var mainContainer = document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer');
 var uls = mainContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL');
 itemHeight = itemHeight + verticalSpaceBetweenListItems;
 for(var no=0;no<uls.length;no++){
  uls[no].style.height = itemHeight * boxSizeArray[no]  + 'px';
 }

 var leftContainer = document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems');
 var itemBox = leftContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL')[0];

 document.documentElement.onmousemove = moveDragContent; // Mouse move event - moving draggable div
 document.documentElement.onmouseup = dragDropEnd; // Mouse move event - moving draggable div

 var ulArray = dragDropTopContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL');
 for(var no=0;no<ulArray.length;no++){
  ulPositionArray[no] = new Array();
  ulPositionArray[no]['left'] = getLeftPos(ulArray[no]);
  ulPositionArray[no]['top'] = getTopPos(ulArray[no]);
  ulPositionArray[no]['width'] = ulArray[no].offsetWidth;
  ulPositionArray[no]['height'] = ulArray[no].clientHeight;
  ulPositionArray[no]['obj'] = ulArray[no];
 }

 if(!indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow){
  indicateDestinationBox = document.createElement('LI');
  indicateDestinationBox.id = 'indicateDestination';
  indicateDestinationBox.style.display='none';
  document.body.appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);


 }
}

window.onload = initDragDropScript;
```

```css
body{
 font-family: Trebuchet MS, Lucida Sans Unicode, Arial, sans-serif; /* Font to use */
 background-color:#E2EBED;
}
#footer{
 height:30px;
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align:right;
 clear:both;
 padding-right:3px;
 background-color:#317082;
 margin-top:2px;
 width:1250px;
}
#footer form{
 margin:0px;
 margin-top:2px;
}
#dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer{ /* Main container for this script */
 width:100%;
 height:2250px;
 border:1px solid #317082;
 background-color:#FFF;
 -moz-user-select:none;
}
#dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer ul{ /* General rules for all <ul> */
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-left:0px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
 padding:2px;
}

#dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer li,#dragContent li,li#indicateDestination{ /* Movable items, i.e. <LI> */
 list-style-type:none;
 height:20px;
 background-color:#EEE;
 border:1px solid #000;
 padding:2px;
 margin-bottom:2px;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:0.9em;
}

li#indicateDestination{ /* Box indicating where content will be dropped - i.e. the one you use if you don't use arrow */
 border:1px dotted #600;
 background-color:#FFF;
}


/* LEFT COLUMN CSS */
div#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems{ /* Left column "Available students" */

 float:left;
 padding-left:10px;
 padding-right:10px;

 /* CSS HACK */
 width: 180px; /* IE 5.x */
 width/* */:/**/160px; /* Other browsers */
 width: /**/160px;

}
#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems ul{ /* Left(Sources) column <ul> */
 height:2184px;

}

div#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems div{
 border:1px solid #999;
}
div#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems div ul{ /* Left column <ul> */
 margin-left:10px; /* Space at the left of list - the arrow will be positioned there */
}
#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems div p{ /* Heading above left column */
 margin:0px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding-left:12px;
 background-color:#317082;
 color:#FFF;
 margin-bottom:5px;
}
/* END LEFT COLUMN CSS */

#dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer .mouseover{ /* Mouse over effect DIV box in right column */
 background-color:#E2EBED;
 border:1px solid #317082;
}

/* Start main container CSS */

div#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer{ /* Right column DIV */
 width:1096px;
 float:left;
}
#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer div{ /* Parent <div> of small boxes */
 float:left;
 margin-right:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 margin-top:0px;
 border:1px solid #999;

 /* CSS HACK */
 width: 172px; /* IE 5.x */
 width/* */:/**/170px; /* Other browsers */
 width: /**/170px;

}
#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer div ul{
 margin-left:10px;
}

#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer div p{ /* Heading above small boxes */
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 padding-left:12px;
 font-weight:bold;
 background-color:#317082;
 color:#FFF;
 margin-bottom:5px;
}

#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer ul{ /* Small box in right column ,i.e <ul> */
 width:152px;
 height:80px;
 border:0px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
 overflow:hidden;

}

#dragContent{ /* Drag container */
 position:absolute;
 width:150px;
 height:20px;
 display:none;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 z-index:2000;
}

#dragDropIndicator{ /* DIV for the small arrow */
 position:absolute;
 width:7px;
 height:10px;
 display:none;
 z-index:1000;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
div#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems{
 display:none;
}
body{
 background-color:#FFF;
}
img{
 display:none;
}
#dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer{
 border:0px;
 width:100%;
}
p{
 margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer">
        <div id="topBar">
            <img src="/images/heading3.gif" />
        </div>
        <div id="dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems">
            <div>
                <p>
                    Available players
                </p>
                <ul id="allItems">
                    <li id="node7">Player A
                    </li>
                    <li id="node8">Player B
                    </li>
                    <li id="node9">Player C
                    </li>
                    <li id="node10">Player D
                    </li>
                    <li id="node11">Player E
                    </li>
                    <li id="node12">Player F
                    </li>
                    <li id="node13">Player G
                    </li>
                    <li id="node14">Player H
                    </li>
                    <li id="node15">Player I
                    </li>
                    <li id="node16">Player J
                    </li>
                    <li id="node17">Player K
                    </li>
                    <li id="node18">Player L
                    </li>
                    <li id="node19">Player M
                    </li>
                    <li id="node20">Player N
                    </li>
                    <li id="node21">Player O
                    </li>
                    <li id="node22">Player P
                    </li>
                    <li id="node23">Player Q
                    </li>
                    <li id="node24">Player R
                    </li>
                    <li id="node25">Player S
                    </li>
                    <li id="node26">Player T
                    </li>
                    <li id="node27">Player U
                    </li>
                    <li id="node28">Player V
                    </li>
                    <li id="node29">Player W
                    </li>
                    <li id="node30">Player X
                    </li>
                    <li id="node31">Player Y
                    </li>
                    <li id="node32">Player Z
                    </li>
                    <li id="node33">Player AA
                    </li>
                    <li id="node34">Player AB
                    </li>
                    <li id="node35">Player AC
                    </li>
                    <li id="node36">Player AD
                    </li>
                    <li id="node37">Player AE
                    </li>
                    <li id="node38">Player AF
                    </li>
                    <li id="node39">Player AG
                    </li>
                    <li id="node40">Player AH
                    </li>
                    <li id="node41">Player AI
                    </li>
                    <li id="node42">Player AJ
                    </li>
                    <li id="node43">Player AK
                    </li>
                    <li id="node44">Player AL
                    </li>
                    <li id="node45">Player AM
                    </li>
                    <li id="node46">Player AN
                    </li>
                    <li id="node47">Player AO
                    </li>
                    <li id="node48">Player AP
                    </li>
                    <li id="node49">Player AQ
                    </li>
                    <li id="node50">Player AR
                    </li>
                    <li id="node51">Player AS
                    </li>
                    <li id="node52">Player AT
                    </li>
                    <li id="node53">Player AU
                    </li>
                    <li id="node54">Player AV
                    </li>
                    <li id="node55">Player AW
                    </li>
                    <li id="node56">Player AX
                    </li>
                    <li id="node57">Player AY
                    </li>
                    <li id="node58">Player AZ
                    </li>
                    <li id="node59">Player BA
                    </li>
                    <li id="node60">Player BB
                    </li>
                    <li id="node61">Player BC
                    </li>
                    <li id="node62">Player BD
                    </li>
                    <li id="node63">Player BE
                    </li>
                    <li id="node64">Player BF
                    </li>
                    <li id="node65">Player BG
                    </li>
                    <li id="node66">Player BH
                    </li>
                    <li id="node67">Player BI
                    </li>
                    <li id="node68">Player BJ
                    </li>
                    <li id="node69">Player BK
                    </li>
                    <li id="node70">Player BL
                    </li>
                    <li id="node71">Player BM
                    </li>
                    <li id="node72">Player BN
                    </li>
                    <li id="node73">Player BO
                    </li>
                    <li id="node74">Player BP
                    </li>
                    <li id="node75">Player BQ
                    </li>
                    <li id="node76">Player BR
                    </li>
                    <li id="node77">Player BS
                    </li>
                    <li id="node78">Player BT
                    </li>
                    <li id="node79">Player BU
                    </li>
                    <li id="node80">Player BV
                    </li>
                    <li id="node81">Player BW
                    </li>
                    <li id="node82">Player BX
                    </li>
                    <li id="node83">Player BY
                    </li>
                    <li id="node84">Player BZ
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer">
            <!-- ONE <UL> for each "room" -->
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team A
                </p>
                <ul id="box1">
                    <li id="node1">Captain A
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team B
                </p>
                <ul id="box2">
                    <li id="node2">Captain B
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team C
                </p>
                <ul id="box3">
                    <li id="node3">Captain C
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team D
                </p>
                <ul id="box4">
                    <li id="node4">Captain D
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team E
                </p>
                <ul id="box5">
                    <li id="node5">Captain E
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team F
                </p>
                <ul id="box6">
                    <li id="node6">Captain F
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <form action="aPage.html" method="post">
            <input type="button" onclick="saveDragDropNodes()" value="Save" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <ul id="dragContent"></ul>
    <div id="dragDropIndicator">
        <img src="images/insert.gif" />
    </div>
    <div id="saveContent"></div>
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having with the code?

Comment: LocalStorage is trivial to use, I recommend you [check it out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage). If you understand even half the code you posted you won't have any problem using it. If not, well we're not here to do your work in a 100-lines JS script

Comment: Why do you want to save it? There are many ways to do it.

Comment: If you create a jsfiddle I would be happy to adjust it for you

Comment: @Chris Here is the jsfiddle, the drag and drop doesn't work unfortunately: https://jsfiddle.net/ChippeRock/xwq8995t/1/

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to Set variable with

```
localStorage.testString = 'Hello';
```

And recall with

```
var result = localStorage.testString;
```

Comment: w3 is not a good source, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the jsfiddle. This is obviously the wrong way to do it, you want to create an array structure and save it like that, but this just gives you an idea what is possible.

https://jsfiddle.net/xwq8995t/2/

```
$(function(){
    $('#save_button').click(function(){
    localStorage.setItem('dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems', $('#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems').html());
    localStorage.setItem('dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer', $('#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer').html());
  });
});

function loadSaved() {
  var dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems = localStorage.getItem('dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems');
  var dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer = localStorage.getItem('dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer');

  if(dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems) {
    $('#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems').html(dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems);
  }

  if(dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer) {
    $('#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer').html(dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer);
  }

  initDragDropScript();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you wish to save data you need to use a server side language such as PHP to achieve that; I don't believe that HTML can do this since it uses [Shadow Root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGhKU.png) or also know as Shadow Dom to replicate the code in the browser and the browser has no permission to amend local storage file.

Comment: Having said that there may be a options such as Javascript and I can guarantee it will be a tedious job to do that with JS